# i'm unable to substring values that i get by running a gremlin query, i've been trying to find this on google but found nothing

Tags: substring, gremlin

This is my Gremlin query:

```
g.V('Service').has('serviceId','ETHA12819844').out('AssociatedToService').bandwidth
```

Result of the query from OrientDB:

[image]

I want to trim out the "Mbit/s" from the string and get only 70 and make a sum(70+70) from the query. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There are no String manipulation steps in Gremlin, but you can use a lambda:

```
g.V('Service').has('serviceId','ETHA12819844').out('AssociatedToService').
  map {it.get().value("bandwidth").replace("Mbit/s", "").toInteger()}.sum()
```

However, in the long run I would consider to store the bandwith as a number.

Comment: Thank you! It really helped.